# How to run multiple nodes in the gtest?

Tags: c++, ros-noetic, gtest

I have 2 packages in my `catkin_ws`, *pkg1* and *pkg2*.
I want to run `gtest` for *pkg1* but it requires *pkg2* to receive the data before that.
My current testing class is shown below for the test fixtures.

```
class pkg1_test : public ::testing::Test {
     public:
        pkg1_test() { spinner = std::make_unique<ros::AsyncSpinner>(0); }
        ~pkg1_test(){};

        std::unique_ptr<ros::NodeHandle> nodePtr;
        ros::NodeHandle node;
        std::unique_ptr<ros::AsyncSpinner> spinner;

        std::unique_ptr<pkg2::pkg2> pkg2;
        std::unique_ptr<pkg1::pkg1> pkg1;

        diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus last_received_msg;
        ros::Subscriber diag_sub;
        bool message_received = false;
        bool pkg2_ready = false;

        void SetUp() override {
            ::testing::Test::SetUp();

            int argc = 0;
            char** argv = nullptr;
            ros::init(argc, argv, "pkg1_node");

            pkg2 = std::make_unique<pkg2::pkg2>(node);

            ros::Subscriber status_sub =
                node.subscribe("/pkg2/diagnostics", 10,
                               &pkg1_test::pkg2Callback, this);

            while (!pkg2_ready && ros::ok()) {
                ros::spinOnce();
            }

            pkg1 = std::make_unique<pkg1::pkg1>();
            nodePtr = std::make_unique<ros::NodeHandle>("~");

            diag_sub = nodePtr->subscribe("/diagnostics", 1,
                                          &pkg1_test::callback, this);

            spinner = std::make_unique<ros::AsyncSpinner>(0);
            spinner->start();
        }

        void pkg2Callback(
            const diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus& msg) {
            if (msg.level == diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::OK) {
                // Set a flag or condition to indicate readiness
                std::cout << "pkg2 is ready"
                          << std::endl;
                pkg2_ready = true;
            }
        }

        void callback(const diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::ConstPtr& msg) {
            last_received_msg = *msg;
            message_received = true;
        }

        void TearDown() override {
            spinner->stop();
            diag_sub.shutdown();

            pkg1.reset();
            pkg2.reset();

            nodePtr.reset();

            ros::shutdown();

            ::testing::Test::TearDown();
        }
    };
```

It seems like *pkg2* is not running correctly so that I can't run *pkg1*'s testing.
*Pkg2* needs non-pointer nodehandle as an input in constructor.

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error that you're encountering. You mention that it's not running correctly but also saying what appears to be a compilation time issue.